# Run powershell command as admin with a batch variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, rds

I currently have a problem where there is a process that gets stuck in task manager. I'm tired of going into the task manager and ending the random amount of tasks for my users. I would love to simplify the script that I have set up to not require placing the variable in a text file.
This is what I have set up now:

```
set curuser=Domain\%username%
powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -command " '%curuser%' | Out-File -filepath C:\software\lynctemp.txt"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""powershellscript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
pause
del C:\software\lynctemp.txt
powershell -executionpolicy Bypass -command "start-process -filepath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Lync\communicator.exe'"
```

The powershell script that gets called is literaly one command but it requires the current user variable.  I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to get the Run As switch to work in just calling the powershell command. Instead I made a text file to hold the variable and then I delete it after its done being used. the only problem is that I would love to just pass the %curuser% variable right into the powershell call for example:

```
powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -command "get-process -includeUsername | Where-Object {$_.Username -eq %curuser% -and $_.processname -eq "communicator"} | Stop-Process -force" -verb runas
```

The reason I want to do that, is because if this gets ran twice on the same host, the current user wont be the current user and its set for failure.

I was also looking at the taskkill.exe but I need to make sure it doesn't just end a random task because the users are using a shared rds host. so if I end task it needs to be for that user.  If anyone has any ideas on better way of fixing this bug with Microsoft Lync 2010, Please let me know. im just setting up a bandaid for when it opens 50 communicator processes which makes the program unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I ended up finding a different solution after digging into the filter for taskkill.exe

```
set curuser=Domain\%username%
taskkill.exe /f /fi "USERNAME eq %curuser%" /im communicator.exe
ping pleasesleep.com
powershell -executionpolicy Bypass -command "start-process -filepath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Lync\communicator.exe'"
```

I've tested it on my local machine and am going to test tomorrow when the tickets come in.

I still am curious about my initial question though:

If I did want to pass paramaters to a powershell script that is being run as admin, How would I do so from a batch file?